# Как узнать частоту обновления экрана

Tags: java, android

Создал класс `SurfaceView`, который вывожу на экран.

В своём потоке `SurfaceView` рисует background и поверх картинку которая движется, её X-координата в каждом цикле `run()` увеличивается на 1. Задержку времени я не добавлял.

В результате картинка медленно движется слева-направо.

Подскажите, как мне узнать частоту с которой выполняется цикл в методе `run()` в параллельном потоке? Это какое-то стандартное значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Номинальную частоту обновления экрана можно узнать, вызвав `android.view.Display.Display.getRefreshRate`. Более реалистичные данные можно получить, зарегистрировав функцию обратного вызова посредством `AChoreographer_registerRefreshRateCallback`. Оба метода на удивление кривые, так как первый почему-то возвращает `float`, а второй - наносекунды. А с какой частатой там у вас вызывается цикл run - это надо мерять в самом этом цикле. При этом по-хорошему инкремент движения картинки не должен быть фиксирован и привязан к частоте вызова.

Comment: т.е. я должен вычислить время прошедшее с последнего инкремента движения и в зависимости от него вычислить инкремент движения текущего цикла? Вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: @gibsonff ну хотя бы так